# How to add a listener to know when the fragment change in the FragmentContainerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Inside the `activity_main` file, There is `FragmentContainerView`, How to add a listener to know when the fragment change in the `FragmentContainerView`?

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: I don't know if you can use the component, but another solution could be that the fragment can notify to the activity that is initialized, for example trying to cast the parentActivity and notify it, or emit a flow data and the activity is subscribing to this flow

Comment: @ManuelMato I don't use the navigation component

Comment: @ManuelMato I can solve the problem in a lot of ways but I'm asking if there is a callback created for that job instead of finding another way?

Answer (score 1):

listen fragment attach event by this:

```kotlin
navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.addFragmentOnAttachListener { _, fragment ->
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ${fragment.javaClass.canonicalName}")
}
```

BUT, navigationUp do not invoke attach listener.